# Formatting the output in shell

Tags: shell, awk, sed

After executing some commands in shell I am getting the output as below,

```
file1.txt@@/main/v1/v2/v3/v4/v5/v6/v7/v8/v9/v10/5
file2.txt@@/main/v4/v5/v6/v7/v8/v9/v10/4 
file3.txt@@/main/v9/v10/8
```

Please tell me which commands I can apply to get the final output as below, simply the file name and the last 5 characters in each line

```
file1.txt  v10/5 
file2.txt  v10/4 
file3.txt  v10/8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F"[@/]" '{print $1,$(NF-1)"/"$NF}' file
file1.txt v10/5
file2.txt v10/4
file3.txt v10/8
```

Separate text using `@` and `/`, print first field, second last field and last field.

If tab is needed:

```
awk -F"[@/]" '{print $1"\t"$(NF-1)"/"$NF}' file
file1.txt       v10/5
file2.txt       v10/4
file3.txt       v10/8
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the end of your pipeline:

```
sed 's!@@.*/\([^/]*/[^/]*$\)!\t\1!'
```

Comment: this is not working on "tcsh" shell, working only on bash shell. I am using "tcsh" shell. Below is the error on tcsh shell,  

esekilvxen320 [7:44am] [/home/shell] -> cat opt | sed 's!@@.*/\([^/]*/[^/]*$\)!\t\1!'   

@@.: Event not found.

Comment: To work in `tcsh`, replace the `!` with `%` or some other character (control-A works).

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk -F'@@' '{print $1, substr($2, length($2)-4)}' filename
```